# How to use conditional formatting in the cell with drop down list?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have two go-downs (lets say G-1 & G-2) and Trucks will be loading from the go-downs. This G-1 and G-2 will be in a drop down list in cell D1. If i am selecting G-1 from the drop down list I have to validate using conditional formatting: stock>=Nominated quantity & truck capacity <= 30 mt & >=10 mt. If the condition satisfies D1 should be highlighted with GREEN and if not it should be be highlighted with red. In the Same cell if I am selecting G-2, I have to validate same condition based on different values.

Cell A1 = Stock

Cell B1 = Nominated quantity

Cell C1 = Truck Capacity

Cell D1 = Drop down list with options "G-1", "G-2".

Answer (score 0):

First remove any previous conditional formatting rules for D1 that have not worked out. This is not a time to keep previous bad efforts in the hope they can be fixed later.

Select D1 and choose Home ► Conditional Formatting >New Rule. Use the *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* option and supply the following for the *Format values where this formula is true:* text box.

```
=and($A1>=$B1, $C1>=if($D1="G-1", 10, 20), $C1<=if($D1="G-1", 30, 40))
```

Click <kbd>Format</kbd> and select a green *Fill*. Click OK to accept the formatting option(s) and then OK again to create the new rule.

Repeat for red using,

```
=or($A1<$B1, $C1<if($D1="G-1", 10, 20), $C1>if($D1="G-1", 30, 40))
```

It may be that your *Truck Capacity* in column C is actually written as text like *25 mt*. This is wrong. Use *25* and give it a custom number format of *0\ \m\t* so that the value in the cell can be used in mathematical operations.

Comment: But my question is, D1 is a drop down list having two options "G-1" and "G-2". If I select G-1 from the drop down list the truck capacity is between 10 - 30, If i select "G-2" its is between 20 - 40. So in case of both G-1 and G-2, i want the result in the same cell D1. Hope you understand my need.

Comment: I was wondering where the limits came from. Hard-coding these is only advisable in case where there are few choices and the choices do not change often. A [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) to a cross-reference table would be better.